# Motherboard with socket LGA1150: Xeon or I5?

Tags: motherboard, intel-core-i5, xeon, processor-socket

I have 3 [Tyan S5532GM2NR-LE](http://www.tyan.com/Motherboards_S5532_S5532GM2NR-LE) motherbords. The wholesaler didn't yet shipped the mathcing Intel Xeon E3-1230v3 processors.
I'd like to start preparing the 3 servers so I think using temporary processors until the Xeon are delivered.

The [motherboard's documentation](http://www.tyan.com/support_download_cpu2.aspx?socketid=29) says only Xeon processors can be used.
I have some Intel i5-4430S (same LGA1150 socket). I wonder if I can anyway use them.
As it is the same socket, what could be a problem ? BIOS ? Desing ? Components ?

Comment: I would try it. Maybe the mainboard will not support the iGPU.

Comment: I guarantee it won't post with i5s

Comment: In case you use ECC memory, you can't use a Core i5 CPU. And most server motherboards can only run Xeon CPU because the BIOS and/or chipset designed for that only. You may find confirmation while reading BIOS changelogs.

Answer (score 3):

Tyan S5532GM2NR-LE motherboards support Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3 & 4th Gen. Core i3 series processors. There is no problem with bios, Thermal Design Power (TDP) wattage   Max up to 95W and for i5-4430s it is 84w so no problem in Thermal design. I think there is no problem in running. But the performance may be